# Can `require` in NodeJS be thought of as loading the file in the lexical position of the require?

Tags: node.js, require

Can `require` in NodeJS be thought of as loading and running the file in the lexical position of the `require`, but bounded by a module boundary (module scope)?

```
1: console.log('foo');
2: var bar = require('bar'); // Loaded and evaluated in after line 1 is evaluated?
3: console.log('bam'); // Run after the contents of bar has been loaded and evaluated?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the first call to `require("bar")` in a given Node process. Subsequent calls to `require("bar")` return a cached copy.

If your code constitutes an entire program you can guarantee that line 1 executes before `bar` is evaluated.

If it forms part of a program you can't guarantee this because `bar` may have been evaluated in an earlier call to `require("bar")`.

In either scenario you can guarantee that line 3 is executed after `bar` is evaluated.

Further reading:

- [How `require` actually works](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)
- [Node module docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Comment: Be aware that `require` is a blocking call and will therefore block the event loop while loading the module.

Comment: Not just a cached copy but a proper singleton. You may use this fact to "cheat" when you need singletons - you don't need to implement singletons in node.js because `module.exports` is implemented as a singleton